# How to check empty input in command parser

Tags: c

In my program, I have to parse commands of the user and then execute appropriate functions. However, I wanted to know how can I check the input of the user is empty. If it is empty, I give him a message to input commands correctly. The following part is my command parser which I am using strcmp alongside scanf.

```
void CommandParser(const char* arg_computer_name)
{
    PrintColorful(2, "%s%s\n\n", "You are currently at c:\\", g_c_SystemModifiablePath);
    PrintColorful(0, "%s [%s%s] %s ", arg_computer_name, g_c_RootDrive, g_c_SystemModifiablePath, FM_CMD);

    while (scanf_s("%s", g_c_Commands, MAX_PATH - 1))
    {
        if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "help") || !strcmp(g_c_Commands, "?"))
        {
            FmShowHelpMessage();
        }

        else if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "version"))
        {
            FmShowProgramVersion();
        }

        else if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "cd"))
        {
            FmCommandChangeDirectory(arg_computer_name);
        }

        ...

        else
        {
            ErrorMessage("%s\n", "The command isn't supported.");
        }

        PrintColorful(0, "%s [%s%s] %s ", arg_computer_name, g_c_RootDrive, g_c_SystemModifiablePath, FM_CMD);
    }
}
```

Comment: "how can I check the input of the user is empty."  --> with C, use `fgets()` rather than `scanf..()`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks, I remove C++ tag.

Comment: Add an "else if" to check if the current argument is empty.
if yes, give users FmShowHelpMessage, and the while loop will keep getting the new augment from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. If you wanted to check null empty, you can use fgets. The following program works well for me.

```
void CommandParser(const char* arg_computer_name)
{
    PrintColorful(2, "%s%s\n\n", "You are currently at c:\\", g_c_SystemModifiablePath);
    PrintColorful(0, "%s [%s%s] %s ", arg_computer_name, g_c_RootDrive, g_c_SystemModifiablePath, FM_CMD);

    while (fgets(g_c_Commands, MAX_PATH - 1, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "help") || !strcmp(g_c_Commands, "?"))
        {
            FmShowHelpMessage();
        }

        else if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "version"))
        {
            FmShowProgramVersion();
        }

        else if (!strcmp(g_c_Commands, "cd"))
        {
            FmCommandChangeDirectory(arg_computer_name);
        }

        ...

        else
        {
            ErrorMessage("%s\n", "The command isn't supported.");
        }

        PrintColorful(0, "%s [%s%s] %s ", arg_computer_name, g_c_RootDrive, g_c_SystemModifiablePath, FM_CMD);
    }
}
```

Thank you the user (chux - Reinstate Monica) for her/his comment about using fgets rather scant. Also, consider the issue of strcmp with gets results. When you used fgets, it appends a new line to the input so you have to check input with strcmp like strcmp(g_c_Commands, "check\n").